# Wordpress if Taxonomy Exists

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, taxonomy, exists

Hello I was wondering if someone could help me out. I am creating a single.php page with custom meta data. I would like the custom post type associated with the single.php to display this custom meta. i would like to have an if statement so that only specific meta data will display if the custom post type is associated with a specific taxonomy.

```
<?php
if(taxonomy_exists('websites')){
     echo ' get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Website_URL', true)';
}
else{

echo ' get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Website_URL',false)';

}
?>
```

but would like this to be enclosed in a ul li like:

```
<ul class='post_meta'>
<li><span class='post-meta'>name:</span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true); ?></li>
<li><span class='post-meta-key'> Description:</span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'short', true); ?></li>
<li><span class='post-meta-key'>  <?php
if(taxonomy_exists('websites')){
     echo ' get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Website_URL', true)';
}
else{

echo ' get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Website_URL',false)';

}
?>     </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it

Comment: You mentioned "if the custom post type is associated with a specific taxonomy" - can you please clarify this statement? Do you mean you want to check if your post entry is assigned to a specific taxonomy term?

Comment: If this project is associated with the taxonomy webdesign and or webdevelepment get_post_meta.

Comment: Sorry, but this is still unclear. FYI, a taxonomy is for example "category", and a term is "Uncategorized". So a post can be tagged in  the "Uncategorized" term of the category taxonomy. Can you please use these words to explain your case? In a nutshell i need to know what is the taxonomy, and what is the term you want to check for. And that "webdevelopment" - is that a post meta that you want to check for?

Comment: I have setup a custom post type with several different taxonomies. I also have set up custom meta boxes in which i have information. one of them being "website_url". within the post for example i have checked that it belongs to the taxonomy webdesign. if this post has the taxonomy webdesign then i would like the get_post_meta to display the "website_url" within the single.php

Comment: I've posted an answer - since i'm not sure i understand you at 100%, i've submitted 2 different solutions - one of them might be what you actually need, so feel free to give them a try.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if i understand you at 100%, so i'm providing 2 versions of the code - feel free to try them both.

**Version 1:** Checks if the post has been assigned to a term "webdesign" of the taxonomy "category":

```
if ( has_term('webdesign', 'category') ) {
    $website = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Website_URL', 1);
    echo '<li>' . $website . '</li>';
}
```

**Version 2:** Checks if the post has any terms of the taxonomy "webdesign":

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'webdesign');
if($terms && is_array($terms)) {
    $website = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Website_URL', 1);
    echo '<li>' . $website . '</li>';
}
```

***EDIT:***

**Version 3:**
Use the following code to display the website URL if the post has been assigned to a term "webdesign" of the taxonomy "portfolios":

```
if ( has_term('webdesign', 'portfolios') ) {
    $website = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Website_URL', 1);
    if( $website ) {
        echo '<li>' . $website . '</li>';        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Marin thank you for your help, but do you see how I have the information in <ul> <li> elements? i would like for the if statment to follow suite so that the get_post_meta 'website_url' will output the same style as the rest of the <li> elements in the <ul class='post_meta'>

Comment: This is quite simple - you can just change `echo $website` to `echo '<li>' . $website . '</li>'`. I've edited my code above.

Comment: sorry marin i forgot to mention that the name for the taxonomies is portfolios in which i have created the term "webdesign"

Comment: That was what i was asking from the beginning :) I've edited my answer to upload a third version of the code, feel free to try with it.

Comment: Hello Marin unfortunately it is not working. it is not returning an error it just wont show up :( i dont understand :0 i do not understand why??

Comment: You need to make sure that the data is correct. So, make sure that your term slug is exactly "webdesign", your taxonomy is exactly "portfolios" and the custom field is exactly "Website_URL". Also, note that the post meta keys are case sensitive, so Website_URL is different than website_url. The code I sent you is correct (i've tested it), so this means that one of its requisites is incorrect.